# In Airflow DAG prev_execution_date_success is None, but somehow not None

Tags: python, airflow

While writing an [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) DAG, I noticed that [`prev_execution_date_success`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) will return `None` when job is fresh and has never run previously. Since this was breaking SQL query in major way, I decided to provide a custom handler via `user_defined_macros`, this is how it looks:

```py
def __get_last_execution_time(execution_date: str) -> str:
    return (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)).isoformat() if execution_date is None else execution_date
```

And this is how it is being invoked:

```sql
WHERE created_at >= TIMESTAMP('{{ get_last_execution_time(prev_execution_date_success) }}')
```

Very simple. However it returns `None` at all times, even when `prev_execution_date_success` (and therefore `execution_date`) is `None`. To me it doesn't make any sense. But as I'm not a Python expert I have a question - can None be some other None? Or what hypothetically could be happening in the context of the Airflow DAG that would break a None checking logic?

**UPDATE:**

`__get_last_execution_time` is definitely executed, I have some logging in it, like this:

```
logging.info("prev_execution_date_success: %s", execution_date)
logging.info("test 1: %s", execution_date is None)
logging.info("test 2: %s", execution_date == 'None')
logging.info("Type of execution_date: %s", type(execution_date))
```

And the output is:

```
prev_execution_date_success: None
test 1: False
test 2: False
Type of execution_date: <class 'Proxy'>
```

Comment: Your macro looks fine. Are you certain that the updated code with the macro function is the one executed the airflow worker?

Comment: `__get_last_execution_time` is definitely executed, I have some logging in it - I updated the question.

Comment: Could you also share what  `type(execution_date)` logs in the macro?

Comment: It logs: `INFO - Type of execution_date: <class 'Proxy'>` ‍♂️

Comment: That `Proxy` seems potentially problematic.  A proxy object containing `None` will not pass an `is None` check.

Comment: macros is using lazy-object-proxy and this might be related to this https://github.com/ionelmc/python-lazy-object-proxy/issues/64.

In short, does `execution_date.__wrapped__ is None` work?

Comment: which airflow are you using ? see the issue, might be related https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19716

Comment: @Emma it worked, thanks  If you add your solution as a proper answer I will accept it. I think this problem is bewildering enough to have a dedicated answer. Also that Airflow doesn't warn against or even mention it anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the issue on a certain version of Airflow (ex: 2.2.2).

##### To fix this (recommended, thanks to @ozs for finding the link):

Update to the latest version (2.3.2). Airflow fixed this issue to return the raw value. (ref: [github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19716](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19716))

##### If you cannot upgrade,

Add `__wrapped__` to obtain the raw value from the lazy-object-proxy class.

```py
print(execution_date is None) # False, execution_date is a Proxy instance
print(execution_date.__wrapped__ is None) # True, the raw value is null
```